# Accessibility Id's for GLKView

Tags: ios, swift, appium, glkview

I'm trying to write some integration tests for iOS Swift using Appium.

There's a part of my app that uses a GLKView (PPSSignatureView specifically) to capture user signatures (they would swipe on screen to create a signature), but I don't see an option to add an accessibility id to the GLKView.

Does anyone know if there's a way around this? As a last resort, on my integration tests, I could use x and y coordinates to draw a signature instead of referencing by an accessibility id, but I would like to avoid this if I can.

Thanks!